# MySQL - Is it possible to merge select queries, so it doesn't have to be executed in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

So i have a query which will get all information about matched rows where items are not visible.

Now inside while loop i had to use select count query to count how many not visible items every user has and it takes too much time if there are so many results in a loop.

Is there a way to query it without running select query inside while loop?

For example:

```
SELECT  categories.name, 
        quality.name, 
        users.regdate,
        categories.name,
        items.name, 
        items.visible,
        items.owner,
        users.username
        FROM items
        LEFT JOIN users ON items.owner = users.id 
        LEFT JOIN categories ON items.category = categories.id 
        LEFT JOIN quality on items.category_quality = quality.id
        WHERE items.visible = 'no'
```

Now in while loop to get number of items, i had to query

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$all_items_by_user = "SELECT COUNT(items.name)
FROM items
WHERE items.owner = ".$row['owner']."";

$visible_items_by_user = "SELECT COUNT(items.name)
FROM items
WHERE items.owner = ".$row['owner']." AND items.visible = 'yes'";

// rest of code here.
// when there are 200 items in loop executing time goes crazy 
// (6+ secs, where with 1 item it's around 0.05)
}
```

**Edit with example:**

Some people asked to see what final code would be, I'll try to give the best i can.

Ignore left joins as this is not relavent, I just added those from the whole query.

```
Id | item name | owner | Visible
1 | Item 1 | 2 | no
2 | Item 2 | 2 | yes
3 | Item 3 | 2 | no
4 | Item 4 | 2 | no
5 | Item 5 | 2 | no
6 | Item 6 | 3 | no
7 | Item 7 | 3 | no
8 | Item 8 | 3 | no
9 | Item 9 | 4 | no
10 | Item 10 | 4 | no
```

In while loop for every user it should count how many rows user owns.

For example:
user 2 owns 5 rows total and 4 hidden, ($all_items_by_user will count everything, while $visible_items_by_user will count only 1)
user 3 owns 3 rows, 
user 4 owns 2 rows.

How to count per user items because if i do it outside of while loop, it will count only for first user, not for every single user.

The final result should be

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$all_items_by_user = "SELECT COUNT(items.name)
FROM items
WHERE items.owner = ".$row['owner']."";

$visible_items_by_user = "SELECT COUNT(items.name)
FROM items
WHERE items.owner = ".$row['owner']." AND items.visible = 'yes'";

echo $row['owner'] . "(Visible items: number | All items: number";
// Output: 2 (Visible items: 1 | All items: 5)
}
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is NEVER execute a query inside a loop!

Comment: Yes i know that, but i see no alternative how to get user id and execute it outside of loop. If i do outside and set userid it will return only for 1 user result. But there are many users with non visible items.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: So you are fetching a list of items, and then fetching the total number of other visible items for the user who owns each item.  This means if each owner has 10 items hidden, you will count the items not hidden each time.

Comment: @Shadow  As indicated by Strawberry and Raymond Nijland, please provide us with sample data and what you would like the final output from that data to be.

Comment: I tried to input more info with result and sample

Comment: @Shadow  It is still not clear if you are trying to get a list of _all_ non-visible items with related data (category, quality, etc) or if you want a list of all _users_ with counts of their items (total and visible)

Comment: Exactly that. I want in every line in loop, to get Username (Visible items: number | All items: number)

Comment: Without having `$all_items_by_user` and `$visible_items_by_user` queries inside while loop.

Comment: Exactly _which_?  What I gave were two _different_ options.  Yes or No, do you want a list of all (or all non-visible) items?

Comment: There should be both - $all_items_by_user shows all by certain user from while loop. $visible_items_by_user shows only visible items. So i can see their stats of how many stuff they have visible and how many stuff they own. It works the way I added in while loop but when there are 200 users or more it just gets overloaded until i remove select count from while loop

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't continue this.  I just can't make sense of what you're saying.

Comment: Thank you for this much help. English is not my native language so i have problem of explaining it understandably enough. Will try to test it and get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that you *only* care about the counts per user and that you do *not* care bout any items specific information

```
SELECT items.owner,
    COUNT(items.name) AS itemCount, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN items.visible = 'yes' AND item.name IS NOT NULL
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS visibleCount
    FROM items 
    GROUP BY items.owner
```

Then you just loop through each row, which will give you the user, total count for that user, and visible count for that user.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dF1eac9fYXvDaG6De54611/0)

Comment: Thanks for this. Do I need to add union or join to make it works with the original query to get all information?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid queries in loop using a  join for aggreated  result  subqquery

```
SELECT  categories.name, 
        quality.name, 
        users.regdate,
        categories.name,
        items.name, 
        items.visible,
        items.owner,
        users.username,
        ifnull(t.count_name,0), 
        ifnull(t.count_visible_name,0)
        FROM items
        LEFT JOIN users ON items.owner = users.id 
        LEFT JOIN categories ON items.category = categories.id 
        LEFT JOIN quality on items.category_quality = quality.id 
        LEFT JOIN  (
          select items.owner
            , COUNT(items.name) count_name
            , sum( case when items.visible = 'yes' AND item.name is not null
                then 1 else 0 end) count_visible_name
          from items 
          group by items.owner

        ) t on t.owner = items.owner
```

be sure you have proper composite index

```
 on table  items column(owner, category, category_quality)
```

Comment: Is the subquery necessary?  Can't you apply the count and sum in the outer SELECT?  (not saying you're wrong, I haven't put a lot of thought into it)

Comment: @PatrickQ  For better performance is better use a  single query respect  a main query then a loop and in the loop several pair of query (a pair for each result in main query ..  )  if you don't like my suggestion you can use the suquery instead of the pair of query you are using in loop  ..anyway  ..  first you should check fot valid result  ..  and then yuo can choice what you prefer ..

Comment: I'm not the OP.  I'm just asking from an optimization perspective.  I could be wrong, but the subquery just feels unnecessary.

Comment: @PatrickQ  .. then post you answer ..  is the better way ..  .. i think the subquery is useful because seems there are  others joins that can interfere ..but could be you are right .. .. the count for owner is not the same if an owner have more than a items.id in this case the subquery is necessary ..anyway you comment is intersting ...   thanks

Comment: I'm not sure where the bad attitude is coming from.  I'm simply asking a question and possibly suggesting an improvement to your answer.  I'd rather help improve your question than post one that's mostly the same thing.  There's no need to get defensive about it.

Comment: Okay.  All good.  The more I think about it, what OP is asking for doesn't even really make sense with all of those joins.  I don't think I'm comfortable posting an answer yet without more clarification from OP.

Comment: Thanks for input guys. I tried to update the best i could